# Как убрать файлы из отслеживаемых по конкретному пути?

Tags: git

После мерджа (без коммита) я вижу, что есть вот такие изменения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в `.gitignore` указана эта строчка

```
**/x64/Release/*
```

Я так понимаю, что когда то эти файлы попали в отслеживаемые.

Я не хочу их удалять локально, а просто нужно убрать их из отслеживаемых для этого есть вот такая команда

```
git rm --cached
```

и нужно указать, что удалить. Вот тут я пробовал по разному

```
git rm --cached **x64/Release/Dialogs/*

git rm --cached \*\*x64/Release/Dialogs/\*
```

и еще по всякому, но не получается пишет `did not match any files`. Я понимаю, что можно каждый файл в отдельности написать, но у меня еще есть такие файлы и не хочеться по одному пути указывать за одну итеракцию.

В общем как правильно удалить эти файлы из отслеживаемых?

Comment: Так они и не будут в отслеживаемых. Если Вы их измените, и потом сделаете `git add --all`, и проверите через `git status`, Вы увидите что, в стейдже их нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $ git rm --cached **x64/Release/Dialogs/*
> did not match any files
> ```

перевод: нет файлов, соответствующих данному шаблону.

что неудивительно: для posix-совместимой оболочки это некорректный шаблон.

укажите полный путь (я не дословно переписал текст с вашей картинки, а если бы текст был вставлен как текст, то можно было скопировать):

```
$ git rm --cached tv_apps/tv_mesh/tv_mesh/obj/x64/Release/Dialogs/*
```

или, если уж очень хочется «звёздочек», замените ими каждый элемент в пути:

```
$ git rm --cached */*/*/*/x64/Release/Dialogs/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню для JetBrains IDE.

Сочетание клавишь Ctrl + Alt + Z. Откроет окно "Rollback changes", выбираете файлы, которые нужно убрать из отслеживания, кнопка "Rollback".